# How do I solve this velocity equation?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, natural-numbers

$$t-t_0=m\int\frac{\mathrm dv}{F}=-\frac{m}{b}\int\frac{\mathrm dv}{v}$$
$$t-t_0=-\frac{m}{b}\ln\frac{v}{v_0}$$
$$v=v_0 \cdot e^{-\frac{b}{m}(t-t_0)}$$

Can you please help me? How do I convert it from $\ln$ into exponential?

Comment: Please don't use pictures for text or formulas.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax - here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: ok thx, im new at this website

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: **Hint**: $\log_b x=y \iff b^y=x$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak thank you mr anton

Answer (score 2):

If you know what logarithms ARE you should know that logarithms and exponentials are inverse functions.  $\log_a(a^x)= a^{\log_a(x)}= x$.  In particular, the "natural logarithm" is defined as the inverse to $e^x$.  $e^{\ln(x)}= \ln(e^x)= x$.

Given $t- t_0= -\frac{m}{b}\ln\left(\frac{v}{v_0}\right)$
Dividing both sides by $-m/b$,
$-\frac{b}{m}(t- t_0)= \ln\left(\frac{v}{v_0}\right)$

Now take the exponential of both sides.  That eliminates the logarithm on the right:
$e^{-\frac{b}{m}(t- t_0)}= \frac{v}{v_0}$

Finally, multiply both sides by $v_0$ to get

$v= v_0e^{-\frac{b}{m}(t- t_0)}$

Comment: thanks mr george ivey, i now understand